# T-SQL query where in(x,y,z) dynamic in list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have a Query that is dynamically created beacause we need to check against a list of int's in the where clause.

```
SELECT a, b From table where a in(1,5,98,34,2)
```

This creates a lot of single use plans. I've looked at a table value functions which takes a csv and creates a table. This Query looks like this:

```
SELECT a, b From table where a in(SELECT Word FROM dbo.fn_splitStrings('1,5,98,34,2',','))
```

This only creates one query plan but it is about 10 times slower according to SET STATISTICS TIME ON.

Any one got an idea on how to improve this?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html. It offers a bunch of methods for achieving the same thing as well as performance comparison of each one

Comment: Stop using IN for anything other than static lists of only 2 or 3 elements. Split the list into a temporary table and INNER JOIN against it. This wlll often be much faster.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, The query optimizer will sometimes do temporary table + Hash Match automatically. The performance difference can be 10x just before the tipping point so a temporary table is still good advice if you need predictable performance.